# Position div box at the end of after ensuing elements

Tags: css, html, position

If I have 3 Div boxes (any number really) ordered in the following manor:

```
<div>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make the div with id `one` be displayed after the div with id `three` without changing the structure of the html?

This is what the html should be displayed as:

```
________________________
| ____________________ |
| | id=two           | |
| |                  | |
| |__________________| |
| ____________________ |
| | id=three         | |
| |                  | |
| |__________________| |
| ____________________ |
| | id=one           | |
| |                  | |
| |__________________| |
|______________________|
```

Comment: kind of contradiction. do you want div `two` still visible? if not it is easy for div two write this `#two {display:none}`

Comment: What possible use case would this ever show up in?

Comment: @Lokase solution to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082481/identifying-main-submit-button-for-a-form

Comment: too bad there's no float:bottom or sink:bottom rather

Comment: @Lowkase, or custom styles for content generated elsewhere (reordering items to user preference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible depending on what comes after those divs. If there's nothing there, you can use `position: absolute; top: 100%;` on the first div to achieve that:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</div>​​​
```

```css
​#container { position: relative; border: 1px solid red; }
#one { position: absolute; top: 100%; }
#one, #two, #three { width: 300px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjnrE/

However, if there's anything after the `#container` div, it will be under `#one` (at least partially, depending on the height; see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xjnrE/11/)).

Keep in mind that if the element is "in the flow" (i.e., it's not positioned and not floated), it will be rendered according to the order of appearance on the markup (and, consequently, the DOM). This means you must resort to JavaScript to change the actual position of the element in the DOM:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var one = document.getElementById('one');
container.appendChild(one);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjnrE/3/

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm, the container needed to be nested in another container which had a bit of `padding-bottom` which made it appear to fit inside

Answer (score 1):

If you control the dimensions of the divs and are sure that their contents will not break your layout,you could position them with css. A bit awkward, but something like:

```
#one, #two, #three {
   position: absolute;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}
#one {
   top: 400px;
}
#two {
   top: 0px;
}
#three {
   top: 200px;
}
```

These positions could then be changed with javascript if you need to.

Comment: the width is controllable, but i can't maintain any control over the height

Comment: You could use javascript to get the height of elements and set the css top property dynamically.

Comment: would be ideal, but sadly not in what i'm using it for

Answer (score 0):

The following grab the first DIV and move it to be the last item in the parent container.

However, you will need to make sure you can target the container DIV somehow. So if you cannot edit the HTML, target the element based on some other parent element with a unique ID or class.

Markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#container #one').appendTo('#container');
```

Comment: well, the main point of this question was for when multiple submit buttons exist in a form and enter is pressed, so will a submit within `#one` still be the button that is "clicked" when enter is pressed and more submit buttons exist later?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you hit ENTER it will submit the form regardless of the number of submit buttons within the form tags. The cursor needs to be within the form though (either in a field or having clicked a label).

Comment: it will select the first submit button within a form, and if there are preceding has the "onclick" attribute set (especially seen in wordpress with image selects), that will be called instead of submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

FTR: `flexbox` support has matured since then, offering a [clean solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159766/1479945).

```css
/* That's all: */
#container { display: flex; flex-direction: column; /* omit the latter for horiz. stacking */ }
#one { order: 99999; /* Alas, no "last"... */ }

/* Demo visuals only: */
#one { background: pink; }
#container > div { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid grey; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"> FIRST </div>
    <div id="two"> second </div>
    <div id="three"> third </div>
</div>
```